# SPARQL Query on DBpedia for group operation

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to be able to contruct a graph with  weight and height of Golf player from  DBpedia. Please help as I am new to this

Comment: Hi - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then show us what you have tired.  The question is too board to provide much help at the moment.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far first. You asked something similar for all types of Tiger Woods, but did not show us your SPARQL queries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is very similar to your earlier question about getting information about Tiger Woods. Neither showed any attempt at solving the task, nor described the actual *problem* you're having. Please include a minimal complete working example and described your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [some](http://dbpedia.org/page/Tiger_Woods) [examples](http://dbpedia.org/page/Jack_Nicklaus), it seems that DBpedia does not have information about the weight of golf players. It does have [height](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/height), though. Here is an example of how you could query for it in SPARQL:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?subject ?height
WHERE {
  ?subject a dbo:GolfPlayer ;
    dbo:height ?height .
}
```